# How to check an InputRadio radio button in Blazor by default

Tags: html, radio-button, blazor, blazor-editform

Using Blazor Server, I am trying to setup some radio buttons within a form and check the first one by default.

I'm using InputRadio within an EditForm and setting checked="checked" or checked="true" but it's not working, the button is unchecked.

Sample code below. TestModel is a class with a single int property called Number.

```
@page "/Test"

<div>
    <EditForm Model="@_model">
       <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="_model.Number"> 
            <div>
                <InputRadio id="1radio" Value="1" checked="checked" />
                <label for="1radio">1</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <InputRadio id="2radio" Value="2" />
                <label for="2radio">2</label>
            </div>
        </InputRadioGroup>

    </EditForm> 
</div>


@code {
    private TestModel _model = new();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your `model` with the default `Number` value set.

```cs
private TestModel _model = new() { Number = 1 };
```